# Calculate count (id) in different period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that allows me to store start date and date for set of numbers of  months

```
DECLARE @Month nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Year int, @startDate as datetime

set @Month = ('5,11,12')
set @Year = 2014

 SELECT  Value , DATEADD(month,Value-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)) as t  ,DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(DATEADD(month,Value-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0))) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(DATEADD(month,Value-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0))), -1)as t1
INTO TempWeek
FROM dbo.SplitString(@Month,',')
```

I got the following results

```
Value  t                      t1
5   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 2014-05-31 00:00:00.000
11  2014-11-01 00:00:00.000 2014-11-30 00:00:00.000
12  2014-12-01 00:00:00.000 2014-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

I have the following query that I can get count(id)

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT ID)
 FROM 
  test EF 
  WHERE cond BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 00:00:00'
```

My problem is how can I combine the both queries in order to reapeat the treatment above for each `t` and `t1` stored in `TempWeek` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can wrap your first query in a common table expression like this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
      Value, 
      DATEADD(month,Value-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)) as t,
      DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(DATEADD(month,Value-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0))) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(DATEADD(month,Value-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0))), -1)as t1
    FROM dbo.SplitString(@Month,',')
)
SELECT T, T1, COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM test EF, cte
WHERE cond BETWEEN t AND t1
GROUP BY T, T1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do a `join` and `group by`:

```
SELECT tempweek.t, tempweek.t1, count(DISTINCT ID)
FROM (SELECT Value, DATEADD(month,Value-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)) as t,
            DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(DATEADD(month,Value-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0))) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(DATEADD(month, Value-1,DATEADD(year, @Year-1900,0))), -1) as t1
      FROM dbo.SplitString(@Month, ',')
     ) tempweek left join
     test EF
     on cond BETWEEN tempweek.t AND tempweek.t1
GROUP BY tempweek.t, tempweek.t1;
```